# ConvertNullDate extension method

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

What wrong this class? I try to reach extension method but cant

```
namespace BO
{   
 public static class Helper
    {
        public static DateTime? ConvertNullDate(this DateTime date)
        {
            return date != DateTime.MinValue ? date : (DateTime?)null;
        }
    }
}
```

If not possible, whats the solution should be

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this method? you also don't need to cast `null` to `DateTime?`

Comment: @IlyaIvanov The ternary operator `b ? x : y` needs to be able to find a best common type of `x` and `y`. If their types are `DateTime` and `{null}`, no best common type will be found. One way to fix that is to cast at least one of the two last operands to the nullable type `DateTime?`. The `MinValue` will be "wrapped" in a `Nullable<>`. Another way is to cast at least one of the two to `object`. Then the `MinValue` will be __boxed__ instead. ***Edit*** Sorry, didn't see that the earlier version of the question was different.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen +1, thank's for note. You're comment is very crucial for understanding underlying details of ternary operator.

Comment: I suggest changing the name because what you are converting is MinValue. And adding a parameter makes it read even better:   `.Nullify(DateTime.MinValue)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is going to be the `namespace` it's in. You'll need to add a `using` at the top of your code file **(the one you want to use it in)**. For example, if the `namespace` is `foo` then add:

```
using foo;
```

and so now you could do:

```
DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now;
var newDt = dt.ConvertNullDate();
```

but I question the input value. Currently you define it like this `this DateTime? date`, but I'm thinking you want the input value to be a `DateTime` like this `this DateTime date` so you could do this:

```
var dt = DateTime.MinValue.ConvertNullDate();
```

and the value of `dt` would be `null`. In other words, if the value of the non-nullable `DateTime` is the `MinValue` return `null`, otherwise return the date, but in a `DateTime?` type.

Comment: *but then use it like this date != DateTime.MinValue and that's going to throw an exception if it's null* What null exception in that case?

Comment: @nawfal, you're right, it won't throw a `null` exception. Let me pull that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if your input is `DateTime?` then you don't need to convert it `DateTime?`!

so i think you want something like below

```
public static DateTime? ConvertNullDate(this DateTime date)
{
    return date != DateTime.MinValue ? date : (DateTime?)null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to return `default(Datetime?)` instead of null:

```
public static DateTime? ConvertNullDate(this DateTime? date)
{
   if (date != null && date.Value != DateTime.MinValue)
      return date;

   return default(DateTime?);
}
```

Comment: Though you may have some good suggestions, the problem was `I try to reach extension method but cant` and so that's not going to solve the problem.